# Actualizar el estado de un widget en tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

he estado probando hacer que un botón en tkinter se actualize.
La cosa es que poniendo lo que creía correcto y las soluciones de otras preguntas de stackoverflow, sigue sin funcionarme. El ejemplo:

`def cambiacolor(): boton.config(bg= "Gray")`

`boton = Button(root,text="tocame para cambiar de color", bg = "Lightblue")`

La cosa es que tal como lo he hecho y con el módulo `.update_idletasks()` no funcionan.

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Recuerda usar la indentación del código que publicas.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("200x100+100+100")

def cambiacolor(boton):
    boton.config(bg= "Gray")


btn_color = Button(ventana, text="tocame para cambiar de color", bg="Lightblue", command=lambda:cambiacolor(btn_color))
btn_color.place(x=15, y=25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualizar un botón o alguna de sus configuraciones es bastante sencillo, primero tienes que crear una función que mas adelante se la pasaras al botón.

```
def actualizar_btn(): # esta función actualizara el bg del botón
    btn["bg"] = "blue" # alternativa uno
    btn.config(bg="blue") # alternativa dos
```

luego de crear la función creamos el botón y al `command` le pasamos la función sin los paréntesis.

```
btn = Button(root, text="Click", command=actualizar_btn)
btn.pack()
```

ahora si nuestra función recibiera algún parámetro tendríamos que hacer uso de las funciones `lambda`

```
btn = Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda: actualizar_btn(parm))
btn.pack()
```